# Android Studio 3.0 RC1 error when adding androidTest package after removal

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

Prieviously in my project i deleted my androidTest package as i didn't use this.

Now i manually add this package to my project.

So i have src/androidTest/java/domain/name/myTestclass.kt

After i try to build the project i get an error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':location:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebugAndroidTest'.
>   More than one file was found with OS independent path 'protobuf.meta'

What is the cause and how to solve this?

I am using Android Studio 3.0 RC1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem when running androidTest, and it seems to be a conflict between espresso and playservices-location on my end. I added in my gradle file :

```
packagingOptions {
    pickFirst 'protobuf.meta'
}
```

Seems to be enough for me because I'm not using playservices-location in my tests, but I'm not sure this is a correct solution.

Comment: Yes, I've done this some time ago and it helped, also not sure if it is good solution